# paid him to repair

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, time

> a. I paid him for repairing my computer.

> b. The money I gave him was for repairing my computer.

---

> c. I paid him to repair my computer.

> d. The money I gave him was for him to repair my computer.

> e. The money I gave him was to repair my computer.

I think in (a) and (b) the repair has already been done.

It seems to me that in (c), (d) and (e) the repair was to be done at a later time and I was paying him in advance.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you are correct. When you use a past tense and present participle, it signals it has already been done. Another example:

> I thanked him for his advice.

*(Meaning he already gave you advice)*

Comment: B could be both right because yes, you gave him the money, but that does not mean the repair has been completed.

Answer (score 2):

I agree regarding (a), (c), (d), and (e). I think (b) could be interpreted either way. You could say:

- The money I gave him was (intended) for repairing my computer, but he spent it on pizza instead.

Comment: Thank you both very much. Then (b) could have three meanings. He had repaired the computer. He was supposed to repair the computer and the money was his fee. He was to spend the money and get my computer repaired (probably by someone else). Would you say that is correct?

Comment: Right, sentence (b) means (i) I gave him the money, (ii) the purpose of the money was paying for the repairs. It is not explicit whether he did/was supposed to do the repairs himself, or whether the money was actually spent on repairs, or whether the repair was actually completed.